# $("#contentLeft").sortable in jquery is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui

i'm using jquery-1.7.1 ui.js and jquery 1.4.4

i'm getting the above error don't know why its behaving like this.

Any help could be appreciable

Thanks in Advance 
--Vam.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at your code? I'd guess the element with ID `contentLeft` does not exist, but there's no way to tell here without being a psychic.

Comment: we need to see your code. Have you confirmed that the libraries are included and in the correct paths?

Answer (score 4):

You have to check:

- jquery is loaded
- jquery ui is loaded after jquery
- jquery ui contains the sortable module (see [jquery ui download](http://jqueryui.com/download))
- your code is in a `$(document).ready(function(){ })` block

  ```
  < script src="jquery.js" >< /script >  
  < script src="jquery-ui.js" >< /script >  
  < script >  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
          $(“#contentLeft”).sortable();  
      });  
  < /script >
  ```

Comment: and item with id="contentLeft" exists?